# Multiple problems with sort method and toString not working

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, tostring

I'm having an issue with a problem for homework.. the issues I am having are:

**I have the following errors on my sort method:**

- The method sort(int[]) in the type Main is not applicable for the
  arguments (Class)
- studentArray cannot be resolved to a type
- Syntax error, insert ". class" to complete ArgumentList

**My toString method also doesnt seem to be putting out any information in the console.**

**HERE IS THE HOMEWORK PROBLEM:**

For the lab this week, you will sort an array of objects - using any of the sort methods discussed in Chapter 23 or the Selection sort.  It's your choice.  Use the following criteria for your assignment:

The object class should be a Student with the following attributes:

id: integer

name: String

write the accessors, mutators, constructor, and toString().

In your main test class you will write your main method and do the following things:

Create an array of Student objects with at least 5 students in your array.

The sort method must be written yourself and included in the main class. The sort
method will sort based on student id.

Output the array out in unsorted order as it exists.

Sort the array

Output the sorted array

**HERE IS MY MAIN CLASS:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Student studentArray[] = new Student[5];

    for (int i=0; i < studentArray.length; i++) {
        studentArray[i] = new Student();
    }

    studentArray[0].id = 5555;
    studentArray[0].name = "Jim Jackson";
    studentArray[1].id = 4444;
    studentArray[1].name = "Craig Creedmoor";
    studentArray[2].id = 3333;
    studentArray[2].name = "Bill Biggums";
    studentArray[3].id = 2222;
    studentArray[3].name = "Frances Freeland";
    studentArray[4].id = 1111;
    studentArray[4].name = "Leslie Limerick";

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        studentArray[i].toString();
    }

    sort(studentArray[]);

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    studentArray[i].toString();
    }

}

public void sort(int[] studentArray) {
    for (int i = 1; i < studentArray.length; i++) {
        int currentElement = studentArray[i];
        int k;
        for (k = i -1; k >=0 && studentArray[k] > currentElement; k--) {
            studentArray[k + 1] = studentArray[k];
        }

        studentArray[k +1] = currentElement;
    }
}
```

**HERE IS MY STUDENT CLASS**

```
public int id;
public String name;

Student() {

}

public int getID() {
    return id;
}

public void setID(int i) {
    this.id = i;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String n) {
    this.name = n;
}

public String toString() {
    return "The student's name is: " + this.name + "\n" +
           "The student's ID is: " + this.id;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The line should be `sort(studentArray);` However please learn to ask questions correctly if you would like further help from this forum. There are lots of useful guides available.

Comment: And once you fix the syntax of your `sort` call, you will find that the compiler will complain that your `Student[]` argument isn't compatible with the `sort` method's declared argument type of `int[]`.  How do you expect a `sort` routine that's written to sort an array of `int`s to sort an array of `Student`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to the assignment instructions, here is what I got from it...

You needed a constructor in your student class, you were adding objects to the array improperly, Your sort method was also accessing the element within the array which is a "Student" and you were comparing it to type "int". To fix that I made the object in the student array actually access the ID.

Also.... Your sort method did not seem to work for me. The instructions said that you could use a selection sort so that is what I implemented instead. Let me know if you have questions.

This should work, let me know if it doesn't because I don't know how your Student class is defined within your project.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student studentArray[] = new Student[5];

        studentArray[0] = new Student(5555, "Jim Jackson");
        studentArray[1] = new Student(4444, "Craig Creedmor");
        studentArray[2] = new Student(3333, "Bill Biggums");
        studentArray[3] = new Student(2222, "Frances Freeland");
        studentArray[4] = new Student(1111, "Leslie Limerick");

        sort(studentArray);

        for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        System.out.println(studentArray[i].toString());
        }

    }

    public static void sort(Student[] arr) {
         for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
            {
                int index = i;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
                    if (arr[j].getID() < arr[index].getID()) 
                        index = j;

                int smallerNumber = arr[index].getID();
                String smallerString = arr[index].getName();
                arr[index].setID(arr[i].getID());
                arr[index].setName(arr[i].getName());
                arr[i].setID(smallerNumber);
                arr[i].setName(smallerString);
            }

}
```

And then for Student class

```
public class Student {

private int id;
private String name;

public Student(int id, String name){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setID(int i) {
        this.id = i;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String n) {
        this.name = n;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "The student's name is: " + this.name + "\n" +
               "The student's ID is: " + this.id;
    }

}
```

Comment: Worked like a champ!